# bootstrap 4 grid mixed up when using margin

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am generating html code using php. I have some information stored in an array called `$persons` and I'm trying to generate a bootstrap card for each `$person`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($persons as $person): ?>
      <div class="card col-md-3 m-1">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=person['img_src']?>" alt="<?=$person['name']?>">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title"><?=$person['name']?></h4>
        <p class="card-text"><?=$person['info']?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine when I remove `m-1` class, but as soon as I add `m-1` class, margin causes the last div to go to next line. I think lack of space causes this problem. How can I fix this problem? How to have margin between divs without the last div going to the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a separate div for the `card` since it's `display:flex`. Also, **just use `my-1`** for `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` so that x-axis space is not effected...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($persons as $person): ?>
      <div class="col-md-3 my-1">
      <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=person['img_src']?>" alt="<?=$person['name']?>">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title"><?=$person['name']?></h4>
        <p class="card-text"><?=$person['info']?></p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/78AmkbWrLi

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to just put another div inside the col, which applies the margin:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($persons as $person): ?>
      <div class="card col-md-3">
        <div class="m-1"> <!-- NEW -->
          <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=person['img_src']?>" alt="<?=$person['name']?>">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title"><?=$person['name']?></h4>
            <p class="card-text"><?=$person['info']?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you don't want to add another div, just add the `m-1` class to the `card-block`.

Comment: that's not the solution, what if I had a border around div.card? which I actually have (default border of bootstrap 4 card)